# TinyMCE vs Xinha

Tags: html, editor, tinymce, wysiwyg

I have to choose an online WYSIWYG editor. I'm pending between [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) and [Xinha](http://trac.xinha.org/). My application is developed in Asp.Net 3.5. Could you help me with with some pros and cons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haven't tried Xihna myself, but I have experience with TinyMCE and FCKeditor. In my company we switched to TinyMce (from FCKeditor) due to the superior support for pasting from word documents and the (relatively easy to work with) plugin architecture which we used to add some custom modules (links browser, simple file browser). TinyMCE also converts the text to xhtml code which is usually better.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend FCKEditor over TinyMCE. I've had much better luck with it (better markup, better managers, better extensibility, better speed, better compatibility, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Try [SPAW Editor](http://spaweditor.com). File Manager is included. Editor is generated from server side code, meaning it's lighter on client side processing.

Answer (score 1):

Of course TinyMCE :)

Comment: The problem with TinyMCE is the lack of a file manager (a free one I mean).

Answer (score 1):

I found Xinha to be much better and more functional than FCKEditor.  If you know PHP and a dab of javascript you can customize the file manager, and there is a lovely set of plugins on offer.  I am also impressed with what I have seen of TinyMCE and due to wider adoption you may find it to have more options.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Xinha, but I can vouch for TinyMCE. It's fast, scales well, and is infinitely customizable. I particularly like the dynamic loading of functionality, which means you only take the performance hit for the stuff you use.

It also includes language-specific [compressors](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Compressor) to further increase performance (C# is supported, along with PHP, Java and ColdFusion) by GZipping components.

Answer (score 0):

Of course TinyMCE it has more plugins to choose from and its easy to make custom plugins.
It only gives issues with ipad(cause of iframes).